# GET request from AVD

Tags: android

When I provide url as 10.0.2.2, the AVD browser is able to GET. But when i give a port number 10.0.2.2:50178/ (i am running a .net WCF service from visual studio express 2012 for web) the response says "Invalid Hostname". Do i need to do something for the port?

I added the port number in the "Inbound Rules" in windows 7 firewall settings. It did not worked.

Comment: When you try to make GET request to the specified ip, it understands that you are trying to connect to port 80 of that machine. If you _can_ make requests to this socket, then it means your http port (port 80) is accesible. Well, the reason why you can' t access to the socket 10.0.2.2:50178 must be a firewall rule that is different than port 80' s.

Comment: thanks, how can enable port 50178? As I have already stated, I tried to enable it by following the microsoft instructions (adding to "Inbound Rules"). It is not working.

Comment: See [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html). The method described here is almost the same as all Windows versions.